# How to make log function in both sides of linear model

Tags: r, regression, logarithm

I'm trying to make regression and need logarithmic transformation for dependent and independent variables.

```
model.conv <- lm(data=reg.conv, log(GINF)~log(INFt2014))
x<-log(reg.conv$GINF)
y<-log(reg.conv$INFt2014)
plot(x, y, pch=19, cex=1.5, ylim=c(0,10), xlab="LN_INFt2014", ylab="LN_GINF", main ="Scatter plot between regional inflation in the 2016 and the Growth of regional inflation from 2014 to 2016")
```

Computer gave me an error "In log(reg.conv$GINF) : NaNs produced"
What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That suggests that some values of `reg.conf$GINF` are below 0.  You need to decide the correct way to handle those values, but you can start by finding them:

```
reg.conf[reg.conf$GINF < 0,]
```

or, using `dplyr` (prettier notation):

```
reg.conf %>%
  filter(GINF < 0)
```

Comment: Can I take abs()?

Comment: Mathematically - sure.  However, I have no idea what your data is or what it represents, so I have no idea if that is a valid operation *for your data*.  I guess the key question isn't *can* you do it (yes), it's *should* you do it - and that is a question that cannot be answered here.